# Laravel Form Request Add Custom Variable After Validation

Tags: validation, laravel

This is my form request code, i want to add new variable after validation success, so i can access that variable at my controller :

```
class CouponRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'start_year' => 'required',
            'start_month' => 'required',
            'start_day' => 'required',
            'start_time' => 'required',
            'finish_year' => 'required',
            'finish_month' => 'required',
            'finish_day' => 'required',
            'finish_time' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function afterValidation()
    {
        $this->start_date = Carbon::create( $this->start_year, $this->start_month, $this->start_day );
    }
}
```

So after validation has no error, i can call this instance at my controller :

```
$request->start_date;
```

Could i do this?

Answer (score 10):

All above methods work but in my opinion I would override the `passedValidation` method in the form request class. This method is called after the validation checks are passed and hence keep the data clean.

Ex.

```php
public function passedValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
       'start_date' => Carbon::create( $this->start_year, $this->start_month, $this->start_day )
    ]);
}
```

If you dump the data now you should see your new start_date value as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this

```
public function afterValidation()
{
    $this->request->add([
        'start_date' => Carbon::create($this->start_year, $this->start_month, $this->start_day)
    ]);
}

public function validate()
{
    parent::validate();

    $this->afterValidation();
}
```

And then access the attribute in your controller as

```
$request->get('start_date');
```

Answer (score 2):

In your form request use function `prepareForValidation()`

```
protected function prepareForValidation(): void
{
    $this->merge([
        'start_date' => Carbon::now()
    ]);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: This runs before validation and not after validation as the question requires.

Answer (score 1):

I made the validation in the Controller. The method has a "Request $request" parameter. I have a I do this:

```
$input = $request->all();
$input['my_new_field] = 'the_data';
```

Comment: yes i know, but i need to create validation at form request

Comment: Ok. Then you can make a dd($request) to see if this new field is present.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this method after success request for manipulations.

Source: [50116187/1101038](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116187/1101038)

```php
public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    if ( $validator->fails() ) {

        \Log::info('Error! No Manipulation!');

    }else{

        $this->merge([
            'custom' => 'Test Manipulation!'
        ]);

        \Log::info('Success Manipulation!');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 8 and above, you can do this:

**Option 1:**

```
public function safe(array $keys = null): \Illuminate\Support\ValidatedInput|array
{
   $validated_input =  parent::safe($keys);

   return $validated_input->merge([
       'foo' => "bar",
   ]);
 }
```

Then in controller, you can access `foo` by:

```
$request->safe()->foo;
```

**Option 2:**

```
public function validated($key = null, $default = null)
{
    $validated = parent::validated($key = null, $default = null);

    return array_merge($validated, [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ]);
}
```

Then in controller:

```
$request->validated()['foo'];
```