# How to check if validation fail when using form-request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I am trying to write a CRUD for an API. However, when the validation fail, instead of redirecting the user to the home page, I want to return `json` based response with the errors.

I am able to do that using the following code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $validator = $this->getValidator($request);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->errorResponse($validator->errors()->all());
        }

        $asset = Asset::create($request->all());

        return $this->successResponse(
            'Asset was successfully added!',
            $this->transform($asset)
        );
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return $this->errorResponse('Unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request!');
    }
}

/**
 * Gets a new validator instance with the defined rules.
 *
 * @param Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 *
 * @return Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator
 */
protected function getValidator(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string|min:1|max:255',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'cost' => 'required|numeric|min:-9999999.999|max:9999999.999',
        'purchased_at' => 'nullable|string|min:0|max:255',
        'notes' => 'nullable|string|min:0|max:1000',
    ];

    return Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
}
```

Now, I like to extract some of my code into a `form-request` to clean up my controller little more. I like to change my code to something like the code below.

```
public function store(AssetsFormRequest $request)
{
    try {
        if ($request->fails()) {
            return $this->errorResponse($request->errors()->all());
        }            
        $asset = Asset::create($request->all());

        return $this->successResponse(
            'Asset was successfully added!',
            $this->transform($asset)
        );
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return $this->errorResponse('Unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request!');
    }
}
```

As you can probably tell that `$request->fails()` and  `$request->errors()->all()` is not going to work. How can I check if the request failed and then how can I get the errors out of the form-request?

For your reference, here is how my `AssetsFormRequest` class look like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AssetsFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|min:1|max:255',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'cost' => 'required|numeric|min:-9999999.999|max:9999999.999',
            'purchased_at' => 'nullable|string|min:0|max:255',
            'notes' => 'nullable|string|min:0|max:1000',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit Test Laravel's FormRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978147/unit-test-laravels-formrequest)

Comment: Friends, please, make the unit-test properly, after all, it is not only rules you are testing here, the validationData and withValidator functions may be there too. [here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978147/unit-test-laravels-formrequest/55389319#55389319)

Answer (score 17):

In your **AssetFormRequest** class, you can **override** **failedValidation** method to the following-

```
public $validator = null;
protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Then your controller method, do anything you want with your **$validator** object. May be something like the following-

```
if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($request->validator->messages(), 400);
    }
```

You can see [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-api-validation-and-the-new-formrequest-approach?page=1) link too for further details.
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

Add this function to your Request:

```
public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Flash error!');
        } else {

        }

    }
```

Comment: I think the approach would be more of a Http error, rather, than only a flash message, no?

Comment: I am using this method after success request for manipulations. Nice trick!

Answer (score 1):

It's been 2 years, but maybe this will help someone.

You can override the getValidatorInstance() method in your AssetFormRequest by adding(Tested in Laravel 6.0.4):

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory as ValidationFactory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Get the validator instance for the request.
 *
 * @return Validator
 * @throws BindingResolutionException
 */
public function getValidatorInstance()
{
    if ($this->validator) {
        return $this->validator;
    }

    $factory = $this->container->make(ValidationFactory::class);

    if (method_exists($this, 'validator')) {
        $validator = $this->container->call([$this, 'validator'], compact('factory'));
    } else {
        $validator = $this->createDefaultValidator($factory);
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'withValidator')) {
        $this->withValidator($validator);
    }

    $this->setValidator($validator);

    return $this->validator;
}
```

After that, a validator becomes available to you in your controller:

```
public function store(AssetsFormRequest $request)
{
    $validator = $request->getValidatorInstance();

    try {
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->errorResponse($validator->errors());
        }            
        $asset = Asset::create($validator->validated());

        return $this->successResponse(
            'Asset was successfully added!',
            $this->transform($asset)
        );
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return $this->errorResponse('Unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to solve this issue: A `FormRequest` has access to a `Validator` instance, so from this you can check if there are any failed rules or error messages on the `Validator` instance's `MessageBag` instance as follows:

**Solution 1:**

```
if(is_null($request?->validator?->failedRules))
{
   //Do stuff here
}
else
{
   return back()?->withInput()?->withErrors($request?->validator);
}
```

Here you check for nullability of `failedRules` `array` or if it has not been initialized.

**Solution 2.**

`is_null($request?->validator?->messages?->messages)`

Here you check nullability of the `MessageBag` instance's `message` `array` property. It is null if there aren't any failed validation error messages.

Alternatively, you could also use `isset()` which returns false on null.