# MethodNotAllowedHttpException using Form Request Validation on Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

This is pretty strange when i use [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation) on Laravel 5.5, all my post request gonna be 405 Method Not Allowed, but getting normal when i use standard validation, here my code is:

**php artisan route:list** value

```
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                    | Name               | Action                                                    | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST     | api/register                           |                    | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@register              | api        |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Request using [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/):
[image]

My base_api value in insomnia is http://mylocal.app/api

Error message:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Error display messages:
[image]

Router (**api.php**):

```
Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
```

Controller (**AuthController.php**):

```
use App\Http\Requests\StoreRegistration;

public function register(StoreRegistration $request)
{

    $email = $request->email;
    $name = $request->name;
    $password = $request->password;

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'password'  => Hash::make($password)
    ]);

    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
        'user_uuid' => $user->uuid,
        'token' => str_random(100)
    ]);

    SendVerificationEmail::dispatch($user); //I use queue to send email

    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'message on success']);
}
```

**StoreRegistration.php** :

```
class StoreRegistration extends FormRequest {
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:4|max:50|unique:users|alpha_dash',
        'email' => 'email|required|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6'
    ];
}
}
```

This problem makes me crazy.

Comment: Please show the form or a link you use to execute the `register()` method.

Comment: Updated @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: It is related to wrong routes

Comment: I suspect there's no problem with route it self, when i change using standard Request it works properly. @user2486

Comment: show us your exact error

Comment: do `php artisan route:list` and post output

Comment: use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest to extend FormRequest on your request class

Comment: Used already, still error @Sohel0415

Comment: when you send the request from insomnia do you add headers; accept: application/json and Content-Type: application/json

Comment: That's the answer @LeoinstanceofKelmendi write your answer below, and i will give a thumbs up

Answer (score 21, accepted):

when you send the request from insomnia make sure to add the  headers;

accept: `application/json` and `Content-Type: application/json`

that way laravel knows that its an api request and will use routes defined on `api.php` and not `web.php` routes.

Comment: @Leo is it available on all version of laravel??

Comment: I can't believe I lost an hour of my life to this — especially when I wrote docs for my own API mandating the `Accept` header. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error didn't come from the validation.

It was because when you use **FormRequest** class, you are using its default **failedValidation** method which is for web and redirect to previous page with error. In your case, you are using api but it redirecting to a url that doesn't exists. When you are using standard validation, you are specifying your own logic.

```
throw new ValidationException($validator, $this->response(
        $this->formatErrors($validator)
    ));
```

So, you need to make your custom failed validation approach with your api. You can do something like in your **StoreRegistration** class, you can override **failedValidation** method to the following-

```
public $validator = null;
protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Then your controller method, do anything you want with your **$validator** object. May be something like the following-

```
if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($request->validator->messages(), 400);
}
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123558/how-to-check-if-validation-fail-when-using-form-request-in-laravel/48124324#48124324) link previously I answered.

Comment: I still do not understand, which part do a wrong logic? And what should i do? Give me a clue.

Answer (score -1):

Disable `Accept: */*` in headers.

Comment: By what mechanism does this help?