# Can't validate Laravel request with CustomRequest. I am getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to store model data using CustomRequest with validation rules.

**CustomController.php**

```php
/**
     * Store a newly created Exams in storage.
     *
     * @param CustomRequest $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(CustomRequest $request)
    {
        return new storeResponse($request);
    }
```

**CustomRequest.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return ['title' => 'required'];
    }
}
```

It works fine with normal `Request` class.

---

The error I am getting

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Check your browser's network inspector and verify you're actually making a `POST` request and not a `GET` request.

Comment: I am not using api. It's normal php post form submit. And it's working fine when I replace `CustomRequest` with `Illuminate\Http\Request`

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48136262/2568469

Comment: @hatef I am not using api

Comment: What does you using an api or not have to do with this? A browser's web inspector captures all traffic.

Comment: @hatef adding failedValidation method worked, the 2nd answer. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/48136194/4414952