# Custom Request class for validation gives 405 Method Not Allowed Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-10, laravel-request

I am trying to store data using store method and using `VendorStoreRequest` class for validation. However, I am getting **: 405 Method Not Allowed error.** When I change to normal **Illuminate Request** it works.

***giving error***

```
use App\Http\Requests\VendorAccount\VendorStoreRequest;
...
public function store(VendorStoreRequest $request)
{
    return response()->json($request, 200);
}
```

***working fine***

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json($request, 200);
}
```

I am using resource api route.

```
Route::prefix('vendor')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('/', VendorController::class)->parameters(['' => 'vendor']);
});
```

VendorStoreRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\VendorAccount;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class VendorStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:5',
            'email' => 'required|unique:vendors|email',
            'phone' => 'required|digits:11|numeric|unique:vendors',
            'business_phone' => 'required|digits:11|numeric|unique:vendors',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'business_name' => 'required|unique:vendors',
            'trade_licence_no' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]+$/|max:20|unique:vendors',
            'bank_account_no' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]+$/|max:20|unique:vendors',
            'nid' => 'required|digits_between:10,13|unique:vendors',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.min' => 'Name should be at least 5 characters',
            'phone.digits' => 'Phone number is not valid',
            'phone.unique' => 'Phone number has already been taken',
            'business_phone.digits' => 'Business phone number is not valid',
            'business_phone.unique' => 'Business phone number has already been taken',
            'password.min' => 'Password should be at least 6 characters',
            'business_name.unique' => 'Business name has already been taken',
            'trade_licence_no.regex' => 'Trade licence number is not valid',
            'trade_licence_no.unique' => 'Trade licence number is duplicate',
            'bank_account_no.regex' => 'Bank account number is not valid',
            'bank_account_no.unique' => 'Bank account number is duplicate',
            'nid.digits_between' => 'NID number is not valid',
            'nid.unique' => 'NID number is duplicate',
            'nid.digits_between' => 'NID number is not valid',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a curl will allow people to answer your question. Right now, we don't know what you're calling.

Comment: Have you tried removing some of the rules and messages to try and limit what is causing the error?

Comment: yes, after removing and testing i found some mismatch and that's causing the issue. However i provide wrong input, instead of catching the issue and sending the message as ouput it again giving 405 Method Not Allowed error in Laravel 10.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:

[MethodNotAllowedHttpException using Form Request Validation on Laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135985/methodnotallowedhttpexception-using-form-request-validation-on-laravel-5-5)

**accept: application/json and Content-Type: application/json**

that way laravel knows that its an api request and will use routes defined on **api.php and not web.php** routes.