# How to get Laravel FormRequest errors in the controller?

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-formrequest

I know i can get the errors in a view with `@if ($errors->any())` or similars. But what if I want to get the validation errors in the `Controller` to return it as JSON?

RegisterRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegisterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:6|same:password',
        ];
    }
}
```

AuthController.php register function

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    $request->errors();
}
```

Is there a wait to do something like that to get the validation error messages?
I couldn't find anything in the documentation

Answer (score 3):

For returning `json` error response ,you have to override `failedValidation` in `RegisterRequest`

```
  protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
       if ($this->ajax()){
        
           throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(),419));
       } else{
           throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                        ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                        ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
       }
 }
```

also dont forget to import following

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
```

Comment: Hey, thx for the answer, I already found a very simple way, just set the a variable for the validator and access it in the controller.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123558/how-to-check-if-validation-fail-when-using-form-request-in-laravel

Comment: @Sasquatch that would be helpful if you want to access it on the controller.good solution for your scenario

Answer (score 0):

In the Request file

```
public $validator = null;
protected function failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

In the controller function

```
if (isset($request->validator) && $request->validator->fails()) {
        $request->validator->errors()->messages()
    }
```

From:
[How to check if validation fail when using form-request in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123558/how-to-check-if-validation-fail-when-using-form-request-in-laravel)